# How to know where an app starts when you have no main()?

Tags: java, spring, apache, hibernate, jetty

I am in a project which uses hibernate, spring, and apace camel as third party tools. To launch the project I create a war file using maven and then run it using Jetty (jetty-distribution-8.1.14.v20131031).

Now I am supposed to add a new simple functionality on the project startup. It can be something as simple as adding a print line, but there is no main() function.

I have the output lines that the project printed to a file:
http://paste.kde.org/pnhee4u7s

I have read the file but all I see is calls by hibernate, apache and spring. All are third party tools. I have no idea how to do this, and I appreciate any possible help :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a Web application with a `war`, start with your `web.xml`; if you're using traditional configuration, that's where Jetty starts loading your app.

Since you're using Spring, I recommend writing an `@Component` that logs on startup, or adding such logging to an existing component or `@Configuration`.